# How to decouple the hardware components

Tags: raspberry-pi

[image]

Is it possible to make the connections between the Raspberry Pi , Motor Controller and Stepper Motor connected wirelessly?

As you can see above, I have 1 Pi (connects to the Motor Controller), 1 Motor Controller(is connected from Pi and connects to Stepper Motor) and 1 Motor which is connected from the Motor Controller.

I also have a TP-Link Wifi Smart Plug.

My elaborated question is: may I somehow use the TP-Link Wifi Smart Plug to turn on/off the stepper motor without a need of a cable connection between motor<-motor controller<->Pi?

Comment: Short answer "probably not" (with regard to the TP-Link plug being any use at all here). What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: hi @hardillb I don't like the Stepper Motor connects to Motor Controller which connects to my Pi 4 via cables. I need to use motor in my back yard and I would like to keep my Pi 4 in home. So I would like to connect them wirelessly. The TP Smart Plug provides possibility of switching on/off motor wirelessly. So i asked this question. Hopefully it makes sense.